# Using [] after string in javascript

Tags: javascript

The following alerts 100. I would like it to alert 200 but obviously I'm missing something.

```
$blah[1] = 100;
function updateBlah(e) {
    $blah[e] = 200;
    alert($blah[e]);
}
updateBlah(1);
```

Comment: Why do you use `$` for your variables?! JS is not PHP.

Comment: Are you missing `$blah = []`?

Comment: What happens? Any errors?

Comment: Remember, `$` is just a character. There is no difference in `$blah` and `Fblah`.

Comment: Is `$blah` a string or an array? If it's a string, then `[]` can only be used for reading, you can not use it to alter the string.

Comment: Sorry, force of habit on the `$` front! Yes, I was missing `$blah = []`

Comment: If you want to use `$` in your variable names go right ahead. Do be aware a lot of JS devs will prepend variable names with `$` to indicate it's a jQuery wrapped object.

Comment: Though `$` is valid a starting character for variable in javascript, it really should be avoided for convention's sake. There is however on fairly common usage of `$...` in javascript - that is when naming variables to which jQuery selectors are to be assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare $blah first.  Such as:

```
var $blah = []; // <-- Declare $blah as an array
$blah[1] = 100; // <-- Set array index 1 to 100
function updateBlah(e) {
    $blah[e] = 200;
    alert($blah[e]);
}
updateBlah(1);
```

This will display `200`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/khRN3/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was missing the declare.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as it is will not work. You need to initialize the array before you can start manipulating it.

```
$blah = []; // You need this!
$blah[1] = 100;
function updateBlah(e) {
    $blah[e] = 200;
    alert($blah[e]);
}
updateBlah(1);
```

alerts `200`, as expected.

Here are some refrences on Arrays in Javascript:

- [Javascript Tutorial - Array](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptarray.php)
- [Array - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)